# How can I implement a "seen" feature using firebase for different users

Tags: reactjs, firebase

The user interacts an individual element in an array, I mark it as seen, and don't show it to the user

What is the best way to implement this for multiple users? It seems fairly simple for a single user, where you can just modify the array to have a seen boolean and then just filter it, but when you have multiple users, what would be the best way to handle that?

Would I create a separate "elementsMarkedAsSeen" file for each user? and then filter it from there? Should I store the elements in the array that the user has seen? or the elements the user has not seen? What happens if the array of elements changes?

I'm just looking for a high level best practice explanation that won't cause me trouble later on. I'll do my own research from there.

Comment: It really depends on a few things. What's the average and upper limit of users who see an item? You might be best served with a "ItemSeenEvent" table that stores an item id, user id, and timestamp. then you can users, items, and the seen events.

Answer (score -1):

The most common approach is to keep a single value for each user that identifies the most recent message they have seen, and assume they've seen all messages before that one to. So this can either be a timestamp of that message, its ID, or anything else that you can use to identify the message.

If your users can read messages out of order and you want to track viewing each individual message, you have two options:

1. Store the UID of each user that has seen a message in or under that message.
2. Store the ID of each message that a user has seen in or under that user.

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer because you start off with an assumption that seems not relevant to the question (ordered feed). You also boil it down to two options, when there is a third and quite common option omitted: having an even table not under the user or item that stores a record of the two together, like I mentioned in my comment. Then it can be joined either way, which gives flexibility for optimizing the queries, plus prevents individual records from growing large arrays.

Comment: If you have a better solution that you think applies here, please post it as an alternative answer.